# How to use ls to list out files that end in numbers

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, ls

I'm not sure if I'm using regular expressions in bash correctly.  I'm on a Centos system using bash shell.  In our log directory, there are log files with digits appended to them, i.e.

```
stream.log
stream.log.1
stream.log.2 
...
stream.log.nnn
```

Unfortunately there are also log files with the new naming convention,

```
stream.log.2014-02-14 
stream.log.2014-02-13
```

I need to get files with the old log file naming format.  I found something that works but I'm wondering if there's another more elegant way to do this.

```
ls -v stream.log* | grep -v 2014
```

I don't know how regular expressions work in bash and/or what command (other than possibly grep) to pipe output to.  The cmd/regex I was thinking of is something like this:

```
ls -v stream.log(\.\d{0,2})+
```

Not surprisingly, this didn't work.  Maybe my logic is incorrect but I wanted to say from the cmdline list files with the name stream.log with an optional .xyz at the end where xyz={1..999} is appended at the end.  Please let me know if this is doable or if the solution I came up with is the only way to do something like this.  Thanks in advance for your help.

#### EDIT: Thanks for everyone's prompt comments and reply.  I just wanted to bring up that there's also a file called `stream.log` that doesn't any digits appended to it that also needs to make it into my `ls` listing.  I tried the tips in the comment and answer and they work but it leaves out that file.

Comment: `ls *[0-9]|grep -v '-[0-9]{2}$'` or something similar. get ALL files that end with a digit, then exclude those that end with `-digitdigit`

Comment: @MarcB, thx for the quick reply.  Is there a way to also get a file that doesn't have a number at the end?  There's one file stream.log doesn't have a number at the end but all others are stream.log.1, stream.log.nnn.  Also, if you make your comment into an answer, I can upvote.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with extended pattern matching in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), e.g.

```
> shopt -s extglob
> ls *'.'+([0-9])
```

Where

```
+(pattern-list)
     Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
```

And other useful syntaxes.

```
?(pattern-list)
     Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
*(pattern-list)
     Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
@(pattern-list)
     Matches one of the given patterns
!(pattern-list)
     Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

Alternatively without extended pattern matching could use a less neat solution

```
ls *'.'{1..1000} 2>dev/null
```

And replace 1000 with some larger number if you have a lot of log files. Though I would prefer the [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) option to this one.

Comment: Bash extended globs still aren't regular expressions. And I don't think you need to quote the `.`.

Comment: @BroSlow, thx for your reply.  is there a way to make the "'.'+([0-9])" part match 0 or more times?  I tried your answer and it works but it leaves out stream.log, which needs to be included in my ls listing.  Thanks.

Comment: @Classified See update, you can just use `*(pattern)`

Comment: @BroSlow thx, this is what I needed.  I was going to bug you about quantity (like using Perl type quantifiers, i.e. {0,3}) but I figured it out from your "menu" above.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

An approach using `sed`:

```
ls -v stream.log* | sed -nE '/log(\.[0-9]+)?$/p'
```

and one using `egrep`:

```
ls -v stream.log* | egrep 'log(\.[0-9]+)?$'
```

These print out lines that end in "log" and optionally a period and any positive number of digits, followed by the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

refer @BroSlow's answer, here is the fix which will include stream.log as well.

```
shopt -s extglob
ls stream.log*(.)*([0-9])

stream.log  stream.log.1  stream.log.2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can this much more simply by just focusing on the dash '-' in the old logfile format. Here is the minimal version:

```
ls *-*
```

This may be a little safer if there are different types of logfiles in the same directory:

```
ls stream.log.*-*
```

To ensure that you get the one extra file, it does not make sense to generate a confusing regex that will fit it - just include it on the ls line:

```
ls stream.log stream.log.*-*
```