# Match two integers using glob expression

Tags: linux, glob

I am trying to match the following paths other than /dev/ttyS0 i.e. /dev/ttyS1 up to /dev/ttyS99. In my Linux terminal, I use:

```
ls /dev/ttyS[1-9][0-9]*
```

This doesn't return anything. The expression below returns /dev/ttyS1 up to /dev/ttyS9 though.

```
ls /dev/ttyS[1-9]
```

Any idea on how to make the first expression work?

Comment: You need to make the last digit optional, you can try `/dev/ttyS[1-9][0-9]?`

Comment: it doesn't work I'm afraid

Comment: @CodeManiac `*` is optional.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `. /dev/ttyS1 up to /dev/ttyS99` i considered this so i didn't wanted to use `*` as it can match zero or more

Comment: Why the `Python` tag?

Comment: You probably need extended pattern matching [How to use ls to list out files that end in numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792385/how-to-use-ls-to-list-out-files-that-end-in-numbers)

Comment: @CodeManiac: You're treating this as a regex (probably because that's what the OP incorrectly called it), It's not a regex, it's a glob pattern. The rules are very different.

Comment: This appears that you are actually using [tag:glob] and not [tag:regex]. Completely different things here and you really should tag your question correctly to avoid mass confusion. That is why you got my DV at least.

Comment: @DaveCross yeah i was treating it as regex pattern, that's why the comment from OP `it doesn't work I'm afraid` made me thinking why ? it should work.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Yes, what I do want is glob. Thanks for pointing out the difference. I've updated the question tag and title accordingly. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
$ ls /dev/ttyS[1-9]*
```

I mean, I know it doesn't force the subsequent characters to be digits - but because of how we know those files are named, it will always work.

**Update:** It seems you're slightly confused. These are glob patterns, not regexes. But I'm not sure how Python fits in with this.

If you want an exact glob pattern for your requirements, then use:

```
$ ls /dev/ttyS{[1-9],[1-9][0-9]}
```

Comment: It won't match S10, S20, S30, or any other number that is a multiple of 10.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs: Why do you say that? This is a glob pattern, not a regex.

Comment: Good point, I think that is why everyone is confused. OP really should use the appropriate tags to avoid confusion then. (And the DV didn't come from me btw).